# PDF-Export for DataGrid

Tags: wpf, pdf, datagrid, export

In my WPF-Application, I´ve got a lot of information in a DataGrid. Now, the step I have to do is that the user can export the data to a pdf.

Is there any simple way to export that? What is the best plugin for making pdf out of WPF/C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ReportViewer control which will let you save in multiple format (include .pdf).

Else, you can try some pre-made solution as this one : [Export data from gridview to PDF in C#](http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-file-handling/export-data-from-gridview-to-pdf-in-c/)

But the best for me is to search more informations about how to use ReportViewer in C# ... it is a better solution for your problem.